# Linear regression for adversity and cognition variables

Tags: r, regression, correlation, multiple-regression, interaction

I am investigating prenatal and postnatal adversity effects on functional connectivity in the brain.  I also want to test whether there are associations between functional connectivity and cognition (but I'm not sure how to include adversity as well or should I at all?).

I'm trying to find the best way to set up my regression.

```
FC ~ prenatal_adversity 
FC ~ postnatal_adversity
FC ~ cognition
```

or

```
FC ~ prenatal_adversity
cognition ~ prenatal_adversity
FC ~ postnatal_adversity
cognition ~ postnatal_adversity
```

or

```
FC ~ cognition + prenatal_adversity
FC ~ cognition + postnatal_adversity
```

or

```
FC ~ cognition*prenatal_adversity
FC ~ cognition*postnatal_adversity
```

I hope I worded my question appropriately.  I'm new to statistics and I just didn't necessarily understand how to incorporate adversity with cognition